# Plot same TimePeriod from Multiple Days

Tags: gnuplot

My Data Looks like this:
File_A

```
2015-08-01 00:00    424.9563018750976
2015-08-01 00:01    785.7380434263472
....
2015-08-01 23:59
```

File_B

```
2015-08-02 00:01    1.4625096463725384
2015-08-02 00:02    6.0047607076482485
....
2015-08-02 23:59
```

So the Date Format  is: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M
I'd like to plot a series for the whole month but for each day only the timeperiod fom e.g. 09:00 - 15:00.

Here's what I tried:

```
clear
reset
cd 'C:\Users\SammerP\Desktop\Desktop Calc\AIT ALL\CatchAllDataAIT\data'
set title 'Data of Month' font 'bold verdana,08'
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
set format x '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
set ylabel 'Value' 
set yrange [550:700]
set ytics (550,560,570,580,590,600,610,620,630,640,650,660,670,680,690,700,710,720,730,740,750,760,770,780,790,800)
set xtics rotate by 45 offset -1.5,-1.2
set xrange ['2014-08-01 09:00':'2014-08-31 15:00']

set xtics ('08-01' '2014-08-01 13:00','08-02' '2014-08-02 13:00','08-03' '2014-08-03 13:00','08-04' '2014-08-04 13:00','08-05' '2014-08-05 13:00',\
'08-06' '2014-08-06 13:00','08-07' '2014-08-07 13:00','08-08' '2014-08-08 13:00','08-09' '2014-08-09 13:00','08-10' '2014-08-10 13:00','08-11' '2014-08-11  13:00',\
'08-12' '2014-08-12 13:00','08-13' '2014-08-13 13:00','08-14' '2014-08-14 13:00','08-15' '2014-08-15 13:00','08-16' '2014-08-16 13:00',\
'08-17' '2014-08-17 13:00','08-18' '2014-08-18 13:00','08-19' '2014-08-19 13:00','08-20' '2014-08-20 13:00','08-21' '2014-08-21 13:00',\
'08-22' '2014-08-22 13:00','08-23' '2014-08-23 13:00','08-24' '2014-08-24 13:00','08-25' '2014-08-25 13:00','08-26' '2014-08-26 13:00',\
'08-27' '2014-08-27 13:00','08-28' '2014-08-28 13:00','08-29' '2014-08-29 13:00','08-30' '2014-08-30 13:00','08-31' '2014-08-31 13:00')
set grid
set nokey
plot'File_A.csv' using 1:2 axes x1y1 linewidth 1 lc rgb 'red' w l,\
'File_B' using 1:2 axes x1y1 linewidth 1 lc rgb 'red' w l,
..........
```

I tried it by plotting only the certain line from each file but than I end up with hole between the days. 
I thought that maybe the problem was the xrange setting so I deleted that but the Problem was the same

Is there a way to set the xrange so that Gnuplot plots From Day 1 to 31, every Day from 09:00 from 15:00 and without the empty spaces between the days.

Here's an example of how it looks like now:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cannot be done automatically with gnuplot. In my opinion, your best option is to not use a time-axis, but a normal numerical axis and provide your own mapping to label the xtics properly and to adjust the gap between the days like you want.

Here is a possible solution, but without having proper data for testing I couldn't verify if I got all steps correct:

```
gapBetweenDaysInSeconds = 1000
startHour = 9.0
endHour = 15.0

set xtics ("01-08" (13-startHour)*60*60)
set for [i=2:31] xtics add (sprintf("08-%02d", i) ((i-1)*(endHour-startHour) + 13 - startHour)*60*60 + (i-1)*gapBetweenDaysInSeconds)

# for gnuplot 5.0
# gettime(col) = timecolumn(col, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
# for all gnuplot version.
gettime(col) = strptime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', strcol(col).' '.strcol(col+1))

files="File_A.csv File_B.csv File_C.csv" # ... to be continued

plot for [file in files] file using (t=gettime(1), tm_hour(t) < startHour || tm_hour(t) >= endHour ? 1/0 : (((tm_mday(t)-1)*(endHour-startHour) + (tm_hour(t)-startHour))*60 + tm_min(t))*60 + tm_sec(t) + (tm_mday(t)-1)*gapBetweenDaysInSeconds):2 lt 1
```

That assumes, that you have one file per day, and those files are listed, separated by white spaces, in the variable `files`.

The first call to `set xtics` sets only a single xtic and deletes all other. Then I use `set xtics add` to add all following tics in a loop.

For each row, the time stamp is parsed using the `gettime` user-defined function and assigned to the variable `t`. In a second step I extract only the day of the mont, hour, minutes and seconds using the `tm_*` functions and calculate a position on the xaxis given in seconds since the first of the respective month. The gap between two days can be given using the variable `gapBetweenDaysInSeconds`.

At the moment the month is hardcoded to `08`.

That should be a reasonable starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried the code and it partially worked in the line `set xtics ("01-08", (13-startHour)*60*60)` I had to remove the `,` but after that i got a plot. The only problem is, that there is only the first xtic showing up in the graph `01-08`, after that, the data is plotted but there are no tics on the x axes

Comment: would this code work even if I'd entered a different timeperiode? let's say 08:00 - 19:00? Thanks a lot for your code, never would have thought of an approach like that

Comment: Ups, I fixed one wrong comma and in the xtics settings, startHour and endHour were in wrong order. Yes, now it should work with any start and end hours, I tested it with some dummy data. Also, the time values could also be in a single file, or in any number of files.

Comment: could you just explain to me the `13`  in the code? I'm not quite sure the data is cutted at the right timestamp

Comment: The 13 was the position were you had your xtics. The code as is should show the data from 9:00 to 14:59 with tics at 13:00. So, if the time range is alright you might want to put the xtics at 12